# why am i getting a 'null check operator used on a null value' even though am using a flag to avoid it

Tags: flutter, dart

i keep getting temporary red screen with the message 'null check operator used on a null value' even though am using a flag to avoid building the page when this variable is still null
here is a copy of my code so you can better understand what am talking about :

```
class _ListOfExercisesState extends State<ListOfExercises>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late bool isLoaded = false;
List<Exercise>? exercises;
List<List<Exercise>>? listOfExercises;
late TabController _tabController;

@override
void initState() {
_tabController = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
getData();
super.initState();
}

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(capitalize(widget.muscleName),
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: Visibility(
    visible: isLoaded,
    replacement: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: Colors.black, radius: 4),
            tabs: listOfExercises!
                .map((e) => Tab(text: e.first.equipment))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: buildTabViews(listOfExercises!)),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildTabViews(List<List<Exercise>> test) {
    return test.map((e) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: e.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
        onTap: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0))),
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => buildBottomSheet(
                  SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                  SizeConfig.screenHeight,
                  context,
                  e[index].name,
                  e[index].gifUrl,
                  e[index].target,
                  e[index].equipment));
        },
        title: Text(
          e[index].name,
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        leading: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          child: Image.network(
            e[index].gifUrl,
            loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
              return const ClipOval(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        tileColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
  }).toList();
 }

getData() async {
exercises = await ServicesExerciseDB().getExercises(widget.muscleName);

listOfExercises = exercisesByEquipment(exercises!);

if (listOfExercises != null) {
  setState(() {
    isLoaded = true;
  });
}
}

//divide the list of exercises list of lists separated by the type of equipment used
  List<List<Exercise>> exercisesByEquipment(List<Exercise> exercises) {
    Map<String, List<Exercise>> groupedExercises = {};

// Group exercises based on equipment
for (Exercise exercise in exercises) {
  if (!groupedExercises.containsKey(exercise.equipment)) {
    groupedExercises[exercise.equipment] = [];
  }
  groupedExercises[exercise.equipment]!.add(exercise);
}

List<List<Exercise>> separatedLists = groupedExercises.values.toList();
return separatedLists;
}

  String capitalize(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty) return text; // Return empty string if input is empty
    return text[0].toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
  }
},
```

the variable that is causing this 'null check operator used on a null value' error is 'listOfExercises' and as you can see from the code above am clearly making sure that the widget doesn't start building unless the it is finally initialized, so if anyone can please tell me what's wrong with my code i would be most grateful and thanks in advance

Comment: " am clearly making sure that the widget doesn't start building unless the it is finally initialized". No, your `build()` will be called shortly after `initState()`, and since your call to `getData()` is asynchronous, there is no guarantee that it will complete before `build()` is called the first time.  If your widget tree depends on a `Future` completing, use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: @jamesdlin true, but considering i have made a flag 'isloaded' and set it to be true only when the data is fully loaded, shouldn't the build method build CircularProgressIndicator as long as the flag is still not true, in other words as long as the data isn't fully loaded the build method should build a CircularProgressIndicator not whatever else i build since i am using a visibility widget for this case? sorry if its a bit hard to understand my point

Comment: @jamesdlin well i did try your approach and it did in fact solve my problem so thanks for your suggestion it has really made the difference, i still would appreciate if you could reply to the comment i left before this

Comment: Regarding `isLoaded`: No, that flag is no sufficient.  Dart is an [*applicative-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Strict_evaluation) language: all arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is invoked. `isLoaded` being `false` would simply hide the child `Widget`, but Dart would still try to construct that child `Widget` and try to evaluate its arguments (which would end up trying to evaluate `listOfExercises!`).

Comment: Instead of using a `FutureBuilder`, you alternatively could continue using `isLoaded` with a child [`Builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html).  That would defer evaluation of `listOfExercises!` to a callback.